# What exactly is Lazy Loading in Angular2?

Tags: angular

My understanding of the term "lazy loading" is when I've preciously created a long list but only shown 25 list items at a time. When you scroll down the list the next 25 items are "lazy loaded" via ajax.

But what does lazy loading mean in the context of Angular2?

Isn't the whole application js assets already shipped to the consumer? What does lazy loading actually do, technically speaking?

I can't wrap my head around the benfits beacause all the code is already there, loaded in the consumers browser. What are we gaining by lazy loading components?

All the resources I've found mostly explain how to lazy load. None seem to define exactly what it does from a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you mentioned is lazy loading of data.

Lazy loading in Angular is about code.
The build tool splits the build output into several files depending on the lazy loading configuration of the router.

Only when components of a lazy loaded module are actually required because a route was selected that has to load such a component, this code file is finally loaded into the browser.

The main benefit is that the initial load (time to first render) is shorter, and if there are parts of your application that are usually not needed by the user, less memory is required in the browser.

Comment: So basically we always want lazy loading in big Angular2 applications since we do not want to load all the modules-components? Am I correct?

Comment: If you mean that you "always" want **some** modules lazy loaded, then yes. Always lazy loading everything is usually not the right approach. It needs lots of considerations how to split the application into modules and which of them to lazy load. I think the main criteria are usually - initial load (until the users sees the start page) should be as fast as possible, and later navigation should also be fast and perhaps some parts of the application can be loaded lazy so that the user sees the main content already and then additional content is subsequently added.

Comment: In other words, if I want three components on init to be loaded I load them and the other components which are to be accessed via routing stay unloaded until I navigate to them?

Comment: Yes, for example. In this case the easiest way is to let the router do the lazy loading. For that, you would need to split the components into a separate (lazy) module (except the 3 you want to have initially loaded) and then instruct the router to load this lazy module for specific routes.